# Built in Python function to skip row of data

Tags: python, filter

I have a script that reads in a large data file 3GB I don't need all of the data and would like to skip particular rows of data if a condition is meet. Is there a Python function to skip a row of data in a data file and continue reading the file? I checked the 3.2 docs but only found a function that skips chunks of data.

**EDIT**

reading in data like this

```
def read_file(F):      #Function that reads data froma file  
                   #and extracts specific data columns
X = []
Y = []                # Creats Data Lists
Z = []


N =   11912639  # number of lines to be read
f = open(F)           #Opens file
f.readline()          # Strips Header
nlines = islice(f, N) #slices file to only read N lines


for line in nlines:             #Loop Strips empty lines as well as replaces tabs with   space
    if line !='':
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace('\t',' ')
        columns = line.split()
        x = columns[0]             # assigns variable to columns
        y = columns[1]
        z = columns[2]
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)                #appends data in list
        Z.append(z)
```

What I was thinking of doing is putting an if statement in the above code something like

```
if x > somevalue:
    skipline
else:
    continue
```

Comment: How are you reading the data now?

Comment: Mainstream operating systems don't have any notion of "rows" of data - the only straightforward way to skip them is to read them, then not process them. More efficient ways would require support in the format of the data file.

Comment: @Brendan edited to add how I am reading the file

Comment: @Inerdial is there a function that will allow me to not process that line and move on to the next?

Comment: If you're looping over the lines using `for`, you can use the [`continue` statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=break%20continue#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to go to the next iteration of the loop. (That is, skip past the rest of it for this one iteration.)

Comment: (Also: especially for Python questions, please doublecheck whether SO renders the indentation in your code samples right.)

Comment: @Inerdial when it goes to the next iteration of the loop does it start past the line that triggered the continue statement?

Comment: @Surfcast23 "goes to the next iteration of the loop" means it will start from the beginning – there's no meaningful way of skipping the start of the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your sample code right, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
for line in nlines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == '': 
        continue # skip empty lines

    line = line.replace('\t',' ')
    x, y, z = line.split()

    if x > somevalue: 
        continue # skip line if x > somevalue

    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    Z.append(z)
```

Comment: `if line == ''` will never fire. An empty line is returned as `'\n'`, not `''`.

Answer (score 3):

If rows in your files correspond to lines, then just use a list comprehension:

```
with open(path) as input_file:
    contents = [row for row in input_file if not unwanted(row)]
```

Similar constructs may be possible if your reading the file from some lazy reader other than the default line-by-line textfile reader.

Replace `[]` with `()` if you want to read the file lazily.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with list comprehension can you explain what the code is doing?

Comment: @Surfcast23: it builds a list of each `row` in `input_file`, skipping those that are `unwanted()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually yourself.

```
for line in file:
    if 'foo' not in line:  
        print 'profiting'
```

Comment: @FallenAngel To determine whether you want to process a line you certainly have to _read_ it!